TypeError: network.provider.getSignerFrom is not a function
Here is my 00-deploy-mocks.js
const { network, ethers } = require("hardhat");
const {developmentChains, DECIMALS, INITIAL_PRICE} = require("../helper-hardhat-config");

module.exports = async({getNamedAccounts, deployments}) => {
    const {deploy, log} = deployments;
    const {deployer} = await getNamedAccounts(); // getNamedAccounts() returns the named accounts from hardhat.config.js
    const chainName = network.name;
    
    if (developmentChains.includes(chainName)) {
        log("Mocking PriceFeed"); // log to the console
        log(`Deploying MockV3Aggregator with decimals ${DECIMALS} and initial price ${INITIAL_PRICE}`);
        log(`Deployer is ${deployer}`);
        const MockV3Aggregator = await deploy("MockV3Aggregator", {
            from: deployer,
            args: [DECIMALS, INITIAL_PRICE],
            log: true,
        });
        log(`MockV3Aggregator deployed to ${MockV3Aggregator.address}`);
        log("------------------------------------------------------------");
    }
}

module.exports.tags = ["all", "mocks"]; // tag this script with "all" and "price-feed" for easy running

Here is my hardhat.config.js:
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require("hardhat-gas-reporter");
require("hardhat-deploy");
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers");
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-verify");
require("solidity-coverage");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();
/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */


const PVT_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;
const HOLESKY_RPC_URL = process.env.HOLESKY_RPC_URL;
const COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY = process.env.COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY;
const ETHERSCAN_API_KEY = process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY;
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.27",
  networks: {
    holesky: {
      url: HOLESKY_RPC_URL,
      accounts: [PVT_KEY],
      chainId: 17000,
    },
    localhost: {
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8545",
      chainId: 31337,
      accounts: ["0xac0974bec39a17e36ba4a6b4d238ff944bacb478cbed5efcae784d7bf4f2ff80","0x59c6995e998f97a5a0044966f0945389dc9e86dae88c7a8412f4603b6b78690d"]
    }
  },
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
  },
  gasReporter: {
    currency: 'USD',
    outputFile: "gas-report.txt",
    noColors: true,
    coinmarketcap: "04ca46cc-8d3f-4057-837a-a1e060769426",
    gasPriceApi: `https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_gasPrice&apikey=${ETHERSCAN_API_KEY}`
  },
  namedAccounts: {
    deployer: {
      default: 0,
    },
    alice: {
      default: 1,
    },
    bob: {
      default: 2,
    },
  },
};


When I run yarn hardhat deploy --tags mocks, I am getting error:
Error: ERROR processing /home/MYPC/hardhat_tut/hardhat-fund-me/deploy/00-deploy-mocks.js:
TypeError: network.provider.getSignerFrom is not a function
    at getFrom (/home/MYPC/hardhat_tut/hardhat-fund-me/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/helpers.ts:1708:28)
    at fetchIfDifferent (/home/joyosmit/hardhat_tut/hardhat-fund-me/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/helpers.ts:857:34)
    at _deployOne (/home/MYPC/hardhat_tut/hardhat-fund-me/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/helpers.ts:942:24)


The error is coming from your helpers.ts file. Can you share your codebase via GitHub repo?
